# No such file or directory while compiling c++ in vscode include onnxruntime api header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, onnxruntime

I'm very new to c++. I use VSCode and Ubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to use onnxruntime api in c++ to deploy my net model file.

Firstly I just tested including the onnxruntime api header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <onnxruntime/core/session/onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  auto start_time = clock();
  cout << "hello world" << endl;
  Ort::Env env(ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, "test");
  auto end_time = clock();
  printf("Proceed exit after %.2f seconds\n", static_cast<float>(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  printf("Done!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

And there's error in compiling my code. The output is

```
[test.cc 2023-01-05 10:08:28.381]
,,test.cc:4:10: fatal error: onnxruntime/core/session/onnxruntime_cxx_api.h: no such file or directory
 #include <onnxruntime/core/session/onnxruntime_cxx_api.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

My onnxruntime directory is '/home/jiahao/git/onnxruntime/include/' and I have added it in tasks.json and c_cpp_properties.json.

Here is my c_cpp_properties.json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "/home/jiahao/git/onnxruntime/include/",
        "/home/jiahao/git/onnxruntime/include/**"
      ],
      "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
      "cStandard": "${default}",
      "cppStandard": "${default}",
      "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

And here is my tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ 生成活动文件",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I", "/home/jiahao/git/onnxruntime/include/",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"

            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "编译器: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I Ctrl+click the include line in my code, I will be directed to the correct onnxruntime_cxx_api.h. So I thought the include path is right but I don't know why I cann't compile my code.

Comment: Are you definitely using tasks.json for compiling? You're not using something like code runner?

Comment: @alan-britles Hi Britles, thank you for your comment. I'm using code runner but I don't know whether tasks.json is used for compiling.

Comment: no, coderunner doesn't use tasks.json, so your configuration isn't being used, just run your task and don't use coderunner or even better use a proper build system like cmake or meson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question. I downloaded the release version of onnxruntime. And in the release package I found header files and .so file. I added the include path in c_cpp_properties.json like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/jiahao/lib/onnxruntime-linux-x64-1.8.0/include/",
                "/home/jiahao/lib/onnxruntime-linux-x64-1.8.0/include/**",
                "/usr/include/eigen3/"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "/home/jiahao/lib/onnxruntime-linux-x64-1.8.0/lib/",
                    "/home/jiahao/lib/onnxruntime-linux-x64-1.8.0/lib/**"
                ]
            },
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "${default}",
            "cppStandard": "${default}",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                ""
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And I added the include path, .so file path and lib name in tasks.json. Here I also used eigen3 library

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ 生成活动文件",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-I", "/home/jiahao/lib/onnxruntime-linux-x64-1.8.0/include",
                "-I", "/usr/include/eigen3",
                "-L", "/home/jiahao/lib/onnxruntime-linux-x64-1.8.0/lib",
                "-l", "onnxruntime",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "编译器: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}

Now I can compile and run my code correctly.
```